# Plotting multiple points in R in one window (forloop)

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

How does one plot several datapoints in one plot, i.e. in one window in R?

Basically, I want to do this:

```
z<- 1:n 
for (j in seq(along = z)){
    plot(j, x(df$A, j)) 
}
```

where df is my dataframe, A a subset of it, x a random function which has as image the positive reals and where n is the size of A. I've seen the solution for 2 plots (where you first construct one plot`plot (1, x(df$A, 1))` and then add `lines (2, x(df$A, 2))`, but this doesn't work with a for-loop, it seems.

Also, if it would be possible to connect the points with a line, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Now having all the points with this code (thanks Roland and etienne):

```
matplot(1,x(df$A,1),pch = 20, type="p",col="black", xlim = c(0,a), ylim= c(0,b))
z<- 2: (n-1)
for (j in seq(along = z)){
    matpoints(j, x(df$A, j), pch = 20, type = "p")
}
```

But the corresponding code

```
matplot(1,x(df$A,1),pch = 20, type="l",col="black", xlim = c(0,a), ylim= c(0,b))
z<- 2: (n-1)
for (j in seq(along = z)){
    matlines(j, x(df$A, j), pch = 20, type = "l")
}
```

does not give a line. Instead, it renders the plot blank.

Comment: Of course it works with a `for` loop. Use `plot` for `z == 1` and `points` for higher `z`. Of course, you will then have to worry about axis limits. Luckily, R-core gave us `matplot`.

Comment: @Roland, then I just get numbers on my plot. But you're definitely right, the problem lies with the axis limits.

Comment: if you get numbers using `matplot`it's the default option. use `pch=20`for instance and you will have points. Add `type='l'`and there will be a line

Comment: @etienne, ok thanks! Now I have all my points on one plot. However, when I try to plot the corresponding line instead of those points, my window goes blank and all is erased.

Comment: can you show the code you used to have all the points and the line ?

Comment: @etienne: sure thing, I've edited the question.

Comment: In order to have a line, you have to specify 2 coordinates for 2 points in `matlines`, otherwise it can't draw a line. Without the code for `x`and `dput(df)`it's hard to say more

Comment: The line must go through the points with coordinates (1, x(df$A, 1)), (x(df$A,1),2), (2, x(df$A, 2)), ..., (n, x(df$A, n)). x just gives values between 0 and 2.